# gcm onMessage() called but data is null...?

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I'm work on GCM in android, where I'm sending data to device through asp.net server as below code.

```
public void SendCommandToPhone(String sCommand)
    {
        String DeviceID = "";
        DeviceID = "APA91bF9SSDEp-UPU8UwvctGt5ogfrSw0UdilTWlCujqItHcr-eiPJ31ZDI-IeqTbLr92ZOPF31bXtB1_5gNEPHAq82N4ji0stm4cy9U0Yuk0Awhjl9PS02okuc9rRhJobkgOt-ofm5Br0KR-Y";
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        //tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AIzaSyBgCKDhyHnRmmu8jCfmupHVJA8cVkIa-XEZS"));
        String collaspeKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
        String postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.message={1}&collapse_key={2}", DeviceID, "YourMessage", collaspeKey);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
    }
```

and in application onMessage code as bellow

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
}
```

It called properly in debug when I call asp.net service,but here **message** string goes null.

can anybody help, where am I goes wrong...

Comment: If you can try posting what your request looks like (the result of your code) it would help us see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your message should be posted with these parameters:

```
'registration_ids' => DeviceID ,
'data' => array( "notification" => YOUR_JSON_MESSAGE_STRING),
```

at android side,:

```
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
data.getString("notification")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in application

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String message = extras.getString("message");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer almuneef, but I'm done the same thing just you store extras in bundle and then getstring. Which is one of the same thing. But anyway I tried it but still get null in **message**

Comment: Can you check the bundle whether it is null or not

Comment: Yes it is null, that is the thing that onMessage() called but no data retrieve

Comment: That means no data is send along with the message
There must be some error in your asp.net code
Please check the response to make sure whether the message has been posted succesfully from the server

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that the "message" feeded to the parameter was not exactly the same thing define in the server.

Your Code:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
}
```

But in the Server, like for instance a PHP server:

```
$msg = array("mess" => "Hellow World!");
sendNotif($msg);
```

See in the PHP file mess != message and most probably a null will be return not unless you will change your code into

```
 @Override  
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String message = intent.getStringExtra("mess");
 }
```